# Discord.py Unpin messages in a channel command?

Tags: discord.py

So far what I've got is this:

```
@Bot.command()
async def unpin(ctx, amount = None):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    channel = str(ctx.channel)
    x = 0
    amount = int(amount)
    if amount == 0:
        await ctx.send("How many messages do you want to unpin, max is 50.")
    else:
        pins = await channel.pins()
        for message in pins:
                await message.unpin()
                x+=1
        x1 = str(x)
        await ctx.send(f"Unpinned {x} messages from #{channel}")
```

My problem is at `pins = await channel.pins()` - I don't know how to access the pinned messages in the channel. If someone could help that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What error does it throw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
channel = str(ctx.channel)
```

This line returns the string value of the channel object.
You use it in the following code:

```
pins = await channel.pins() # i.e. get string.pins()
```

Because strings dont have the `pins()` function. It throws an error, or wont function correctly.

---

In order to fix this you should assign the `ctx.channel` object to the channel variable. This way we dont convert it to a string by using `str()`.

Now we have a channel object, we can correctly use the `pins()` function with, and do what you wanted it to do.

```
@Bot.command()
async def unpin(ctx, amount = None):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    channel = ctx.channel
    x = 0
    amount = int(amount)
    if amount == 0:
        await ctx.send("How many messages do you want to unpin, max is 50.")
    else:
        pins = await channel.pins()
        for message in pins:
                await message.unpin()
                x+=1
        x1 = str(x)
        await ctx.send(f"Unpinned {x} messages from #{channel}")
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, how would I make it so I can give an amount of messages to unpin?

Comment: Hi @cap, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @cap
To further answer your question. I recommend trying it yourself, and if you cannot find a solution, show what you've tried and start a new question! This way you will get much better answers to your new question. (Better than through the comment section).

Answer (score 0):

You returned the `ctx.channel` in to a string. That's why you can't access the pins. If you change the line `channel = str(ctx.channel)` to `channel = ctx.channel`, your problem will be solved.

And also, you should change the parameter `amount=None` as `amount=0`.